# How to compare number day of the week using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a struct like this:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li data-day="monday">BlaBla</li>
   <li data-day="friday">BlaBla</li>
   <li data-day="tuesday">BlaBla</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to read that data attribute and then check which NUMBER of the week day that represents, like:

```
   $('#list').each(function(){
       var day = $($this).data('day'); //day = monday
       //MAKE SOMETHING BETTER THAN A BUNCH OF 'IF'S CONDICIONAL
       //TO COMPARE THE DAY AND RELATE IT TO THE NUMBER OF THE WEEK.
       //Now using `momentjs` I need to relate monday with the number day of the week. Knowing that monday is equivalent of 1.   
       if(day = "monday"){ var numDay = 1}
       else if(day = "sunday"){ var numDay = 2}



});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
console.log(moment().day("Monday").day());
```

[docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/)

Comment: Nice ! I forggot to mention. As English isn't my main language and momentjs does not have support to it I guess I'll need another way. i'll try to adapt yours.

Comment: moment supports localization [see](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)